# Fixed Table in Winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, tabular

I'm looking for a fixed table, like HTML table to fill data in each row. I took a look at TableLayoutPanel, but this is not what I'm looking for because you can't fill the cells programmatically. Anyone have an idea how to handle this?

Comment: what about gridview or listview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fill the cells from code. See this example:

```
TableLayoutPanel panel = new TableLayoutPanel();
panel.Controls.Add(new TextBox(), 1, 1);
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he3sxc2a.aspx